# SSRS Report Builder problem including ODBC (xls)-DSN

Tags: reporting-services, odbc, ssrs-2012, xls, reportbuilder

I try to use an Excel-Datafile as an Dataset for the MS Report Builder.

Therefore, i create a ODBC System-DSN ("DSExcel") and connect the Excel-file to it.

Then i created an embedded Datasource in MS Report Builder and use the System-DSN for the connection: Connection string= "Dsn=DSExcel"

And everything works fine.
But if i now add a shared Datasource of my SSRS to the report Builder, the Data of the ODBC-System DSN can not be used anymore.

I read in an article here, that this is because Report-Builder is a 32-Bit application and the SSRS are a 64-Bit Application - and therefore cannot use the same DSN. So i created two System DSN, one 32-Bit and one 64-Bit with the same name .But it still doesn't work.

I created two System DSN:[32 and 64 Bit Sytsem-DSN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntxEh.png)

And then connected it in the Report Builder, the connection was successful:[Connection 32-Bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIaRE.png)

But as soon as the SSRS try to connect to the DSN the following Error pops up: [Error 64-Bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Lke.png)

I can see the Data in the preview: [Data Preview with Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grXip.png)

But as soon as i try to run the report, the error pops up again: [Error in Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxY4T.png)

This only happens if i have a shared datasource, which is connected to the SSRS, connected: [Data Sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R22ev.png)

If i try to run the report in the Web Portal, it won't work either.

I had many other errors where i were stuck in the same position - but using a second ODBC-DSN with 64 Bit led me to where i am now :D. Thank you for your help!